# Making elements changeable from references

Tags: c#, reference

So! I've got a C# array.

And I've got a function that returns an element from the array, so the data from that reference can be accessed. Yay!

It would be really super awesome convenient if changing that reference then affected that original element in the array. Is this what static variables do? Is there a way to do it? How to do? For example:

Function A finds an item:

```
public TutorialPopupBehavior GetBehavior(string behaviorName) {
        foreach(TutorialPopupBehavior beh in _tutorialItems) {
            if(beh._popupName == behaviorName) {
                return beh;
            }
        }
        print ("Could not find behavior of name " + behaviorName);
        return null;
    }
```

And then returns it to function B, which then, ideally, would be able to change a property of the returned item:

```
public void SetTutorialItem(bool state, string itemName) {
        TutorialPopupBehavior beh = GetBehavior(itemName);
        if(beh == null) {
            print ("No tutorial item found, so can't set it to " + state);
            return;
        }   
        //idealistic code: beh._isShown = true;

    }
```

The _isShown property of that element would then be changed permanently in the original _tutorialItems array...how do you all accomplish this, or design differently, so as to avoid the problem? The reason I ask is because I have a number of arrays to search, and I don't want to complicate my code by asking the same class to search through the same set of arrays more than once.

Comment: That is what references are for?

Comment: Put some code with your question to see what you exactly want

Comment: Cool! Good advice. Code added. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public  void GetBehavior(string behaviorName, ref TutorialPopupBehavior b) {
            foreach(TutorialPopupBehavior beh in _tutorialItems) {
                if(beh._popupName == behaviorName) {
                    b = beh;
                     Return;
                }
            }
            print ("Could not find behavior of name " + behaviorName);
            b = null;
        }
```

Read this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: Super! I was confused about what it  meant to "pass by reference". I thought it meant the same thing as passing by value. Cheers.

Comment: @Catlard Just declare TutorialPopUpBehavior before you use the GetBehavior method and pass it to it